# Swift 3 manipulating UICollectionViewCell size?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview, swift3

I'm struggling with manipulating my UICollectionViewCell sizes, since it seem the function is deprecated, same goes for spacing. I've tried with this one:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                        sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: 150, height: 150)
    }
```

Which function am I supposed to use in Swift 3?

Comment: You can adjust the size in your `CellForRowAtIndex` and set the size there.

Comment: Oh, is that the way to go in Swift 3?

Comment: Yes, something like this should work `cell.frame.size = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)`

Comment: Since when is [UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegateflowlayout) deprecated? And why would that be only in Swift 3?

Answer (score 4):

you can try this code in swift3

```
override var collectionViewContentSize: CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: 150, height: 150)
}
```

Comment: why it does not call?

Comment: are you sure you follow the `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` delegate?@ Vaibhav Saran

Answer (score 0):

You can use below delegate method.

```html
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        
        return CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
    }
```

Comment: Don't forget to make the parent class an instance of CollectionViewFlowLayoutDelegate.

Comment: @JamesWolfe yeap that's right! But more appropriate way to do is extend view controller with corresponded delegate protocol.

Comment: That's what I meant, you'd have a lot of problems trying to make a collectionViewController accept a CollectionViewFlowLayoutDelegate as the class. :P